# Can't select nothing inside draggable modal window

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Please someone help. I'm really broken my brain on this. Neither select text inside modal nor click on input to type text into it.

I think it's because of z-index bugs. But can't find them.

```
var currentZ = null,
baseZ = 1000,
maxZ = 2000;
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/emvc79sa/1/

This is directive [angular-html-window](https://github.com/acjim/angular-html-window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the directive author set it this way, but your click actions are consumed by this line:

```
Window.prototype = {

    _resizing: null,
    _moving: null,
    _restore: null,

    events: {
        wnd_mousedown: function(event) {
            this.focus();
            event.preventDefault(); // this line
        },
```

Commenting out this line will let you highlight as normal but I'm not sure if there is any side effects.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help!